# How to put conditions on associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Here are my models:

```
class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :checklists_tasks
    has_many :tasks, through: :checklists_tasks
end

class ChecklistsTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :checklist
    belongs_to :task
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :section
    has_many :checklists_tasks
    has_many :checklists, through: :checklists_tasks
end
```

I then have a view like this:

```
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <h2><%= section.name %></h2>
    <ul>
    <% section.tasks.each.do |task| %>
        <li><%= task.name %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

How do I query Section and make sure that the tasks associated with each Section are all associated with a certain Checklist?

To clarify, /checklists/1/show and /checklists/2/show should use the view above and ouput the same sections, but the tasks in the sections could be different.

Comment: Also, does anyone have a suggestion for a better title?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to show the section's tasks which are also belong to current checklist, try this:

```
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <h2><%= section.name %></h2>
    <ul>
    <% # get the checklist's id in url => /checklists/:id %>
    <% check_list_id = params[:id] %>

    <% # query tasks using section_id and check_list_id %>
    <% tasks = Task.find_by(section_id: section.id, check_list_id: check_list_id) %>
    <% tasks.each.do |task| %>
      <li><%= task.name %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this by adding a method to Section.

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks

    def tasks_by_checklist(checklist)
        if checklist != nil
            Task.where(section_id: self.id, checklists_tasks: { checklist_id: checklist.id}).includes(:checklists_tasks)
        else
            self.tasks
        end
    end
end
```

Then updated the view to use this new method:

```
...
<% section.tasks_by_checklist(@checklist).each.do |task| %>
...
```

Since @checklist is nil in /tasks (index), but set in /checklist/:id/show, the same view works as intended for both controller actions.

I'm still curious if there is a way to do it by editing `@sections = Section.all` in the controller to something more clever.